# How can I parse specific text in python that would include everything else that was in the same line

Tags: python, parsing

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can parse specific text but instead of just parsing the specific text I want to parse everything that was included in the same line that had the text I was looking for

my code

```
txt_file = open("test.txt",'r')
txt = txt_file.read()
txt_file.close()

count = 0

print("counting")
for data in txt:
    data = txt.strip()
    if data.find("holiday"):
        count = count + 1
print(count)
print(data)
```

txt file example

1. on July 4 I'm going to celebrate a holiday called July 4th!
2. on January 1st it's new years a international holiday!
3. on November 30st I'm going to celebrate my friends birthday

---

I am trying to parse all of the lines in the txt file that would include holiday and the rest of the text included in the sentence and print it out by line like this

1. on July 4 I'm going to celebrate a holiday called July 4th!
2. on January 1st it's new years a international holiday!

I was searching up how I can do this before coming here but did not find what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `readlines()` instead of `read()` so you'll get a list with a string for each line instead of just getting one string for the entire file:

```py
txt_file = open("test.txt",'r')
txt = txt_file.readlines()
txt_file.close()
```

I would also recommend using `with` for file reading because it automatically closes the file even if an error occurs:

```py
with open("test.txt", "r") as txt_file:
    txt = txt_file.readlines()
```

The you can find the lines that contains the string "holidays" using the `in` operator. Then if you move your print statement inside the loop it will print each matching line:

```py
for data in txt:
    if "holiday" in data:
        count = count + 1
        print(data)
```

If you want to process the matching lines more later you can also save them to a separate data structure instead of just printing them:

```py
matches = []

for data in txt:
    if "holiday" in data:
        count = count + 1
        matches.append(data)

print(matches)
```